# VMware workstation 10.0.3 bridge network not working

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, bridge, bridging

I have an issue on vmware workstation bridge netwoking, for the first install it work just perfectly, but when i restart VMware it cut up. 
I have start the repair but it not working. When i do a full unistall of the program, i got 
it work for the first time, but after retarting i cut up again.